# Symfony2 - form entity field with multiple , data not preserved after choices set

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm using form to edit some data. 
one of the form field:

```
$builder ->add('cities', 'entity', array(
    'class'    => 'Vendor\SomeBundle\Entity\City',
    'multiple' => true
));
```

everthing works fine - i have some preselected cities in accordance with the database.

Now i want to limit choices to cities form specific country.
So I get collection of cities and set 'choices' option:

```
$builder ->add('cities', 'entity', array(
    'class'    => 'Vendor\SomeBundle\Entity\City',
    'multiple' => true,
    'choices'  => $citiesCollection
));
```

The choice list is limited but no cities are selected.

i try to set this preselected cities using 'data' option but this also does not work

```
$builder ->add('cities', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'Vendor\SomeBundle\Entity\City',
    'multiple' => true,
    'choices'  => $citiesCollection
    'data'     => $citiesSelected
));
```

trying different approaches, passing ArrayCollection, array, array of keys but nothing works...
It is even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The working solution - set 'query_builder" option instead of 'choices'

```
$builder ->add('cities', 'entity', array(
    'class'    => 'Vendor\SomeBundle\Entity\City',
    'multiple' => true,
    'query_builder'  => $citiesQueryBuilder
));
```

now rendered form has selected cities

Answer (score -1):

I think that assigning the $citiesSelected array to the cities field of the base entity assigned to the form will make the trick.

Comment: But the base entity is loaded from database and it already has proper collection of cities. Adding a 'choices' option in form builder somehow clears this collection - there is no selected cities in rendered form